# Is there a recourse for a retired professor who was denied Emeritus title?

Tags: career-path, professor-emeritus, retirement

I know of a recently retired professor who has taught over 35 years, and has published over 100 papers, and has filed multiple patents as well.

His college dean does not agree that he should get the Emeritus title.

The main reason he wants to obtain this title is to retain his office, in which he has a large library of books and materials

Is there anything he can do here?  How would he challenge the decision of his college dean?  Do universities usually have a system to granting the Emeritus title?

Comment: This is a local question answered by local rules. But since it is normally an honorific, not a contractural matter, probably nothing could be done that is effective. You can embarrass people, of course, but it isn't effective in getting the title.

Comment: @Buffy - Thanks , I hear you on that.  I think the main benefit is that he would be able to retain his former office

Comment: Possibly he would be permitted the space without the title.

Comment: In the U.S., many emeritus professors do not retain their original office, but only have a shared office with other emeritus profs. Many places, space is the inflexible resource.

Comment: @paulgarrett - not just an inflexible resource, but a highly political hot potato fought over with homicidal fury...